# Action Listener never used locally

Tags: java, listener

ActionListener is never used locally, i know i am missing something but i cant figure it out. I cant understand why it is never used when its added to the Actionlisteners list already

```
public class GUIinterface extends JFrame{

    JMenuBar MenuBar;
    JMenu file;
    JMenu help;
    JMenuItem load;
    JMenuItem save;
    JMenuItem about;
    JTextField commandLine;
    GraphicsPanel gp;

    public GUIinterface() {
        setTitle("Menu");
        setSize(640,480);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gp = new GraphicsPanel();
        add(gp);

        MenuBar = new JMenuBar();
        file = new JMenu("File");
        help = new JMenu("Help");
        load = new JMenuItem("Load");
        save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        about = new JMenuItem("About");
        commandLine = new JTextField();

        file.add(load);
        file.add(save);
        help.add(about);

        MenuBar.add(file);
        MenuBar.add(help);

        add(MenuBar);
        add(commandLine, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        file.addMenuListener(new myMenuListener());
        load.addActionListener(new myActionListener());
        save.addActionListener(new myActionListener());
        about.addActionListener(new myActionListener());

        setJMenuBar(MenuBar);
        setVisible(true);

        commandLine.addActionListener(new myActionListener());
    }

    private class myActionListener implements ActionListener{
        private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == about) {
                    System.out.println("A");
                    gp.about();
                }
            }
        }            

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(commandLine.getText());
            if (e.getSource() == commandLine) {
                if (commandLine.getText().contains("penup")) {
                    gp.penUp();
                    commandLine.setText("");
                } else if (commandLine.getText().contains("pendown")) {
                    gp.penDown();
                    commandLine.setText("");
                } else if (commandLine.getText().contains("turnleft")) {
                    gp.turnLeft();
                    commandLine.setText("");
                } else if (commandLine.getText().contains("turnright")) {
                    gp.turnRight();
                    commandLine.setText("");
                } else if (commandLine.getText().contains("forward")) {
                    gp.forward(50);
                    commandLine.setText("");
                } else if (commandLine.getText().contains("backward")) {
                    gp.forward(-50);
                    commandLine.setText("");
                } else if (commandLine.getText().contains("black")) {
                    gp.setPenColour(Color.black);
                    commandLine.setText("");
                } else if (commandLine.getText().contains("red")) {
                    gp.setPenColour(Color.red);
                    commandLine.setText("");
                } else if (commandLine.getText().contains("green")) {
                    gp.setPenColour(Color.green);
                    commandLine.setText("");
                }  
            }
        }
    }
    private class myMenuListener implements MenuListener{

        public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("cancel");   
        }

        public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("deselect"); 
        }

        public void menuSelected(MenuEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("select");   
        }
    }
}
```

The listener should call the gp.about() method when pressed which creates a simple graphic

Comment: You have  a second `myActionListener ` class within the first `myActionListener `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ActionListener, `MyActionListener` and `myActionListener`, and you only using `myActionListener`

Tryto unify both into one, and there would be something like that:

```
private class myActionListener implements ActionListener{


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(commandLine.getText());
        if (e.getSource() == about) {
            System.out.println("A");
            gp.about();
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == commandLine)
        {
            if (commandLine.getText().contains("penup"))
            {
                gp.penUp();
                commandLine.setText("");
            }
            else if (commandLine.getText().contains("pendown"))
            {
                gp.penDown();
                commandLine.setText("");
            }
            else if (commandLine.getText().contains("turnleft"))
            {
                gp.turnLeft();
                commandLine.setText("");
            }
            else if (commandLine.getText().contains("turnright"))
            {
                gp.turnRight();
                commandLine.setText("");
            }
            else if (commandLine.getText().contains("forward"))
            {
                gp.forward(50);
                commandLine.setText("");
            }
            else if (commandLine.getText().contains("backward"))
            {
                gp.forward(-50);
                commandLine.setText("");
            }
            else if (commandLine.getText().contains("black"))
            {
                gp.setPenColour(Color.black);
                commandLine.setText("");
            }
            else if (commandLine.getText().contains("red"))
            {
                gp.setPenColour(Color.red);
                commandLine.setText("");
            } 
            else if (commandLine.getText().contains("green"))
            {
                gp.setPenColour(Color.green);
                commandLine.setText("");
            } 

        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
By [naming convenction](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) in java

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form, such as URL or HTML).

So I suggest you use `MyActionListener` instaead `myActionListener`

Comment: This fixed the issue but the button just does nothing?

Comment: You must program what you want each button to do.
For example: `if (e.getSource() == save ) { //Do stuff`

Comment: thats what gp.about is its from a referenced library so its a premade command that i imported